# Running and Printing a Access Report via VBScript and/or Command Line

Tags: ms-access, command-line

I need to run and print a Access report via vbscript or a command line. I have looked in many places but I remain lost. I need to do this for automation purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [How to use command-line switches in Microsoft Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207), I don't see an option to open a specific report from the command line.  However, you could do it indirectly by creating a macro to print your report and including the macro name following the /x switch on the command line.

```
"Path to MSACCESS.EXE" "Path to your db file" /x YourMacroName
```

I don't do much with macros.  If creating a macro to print the report isn't suitable, you could create a VBA function to do it, and design the macro to simply run your function.

If you prefer VBScript, try this.  It might need work beyond changing the values of the constants.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim appAccess
Const cstrFolder = "C:\Access\webforums\"
Const cstrMdb = "whiteboard2003.mdb"
Const cstrReport = "rptFoo"

Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase cstrFolder & cstrMdb, False
appAccess.DoCmd.OpenReport cstrReport, 0 ' acViewNormal = 0
appAccess.DoCmd.Close 3, cstrReport ' acReport = 3
appAccess.Quit
Set appAccess = Nothing
```

Comment: The VBScript will print the report as well? Don't I need to specify the printer? Thank you for your help! :-)

Comment: It will print to the default printer.  If you don't have a default printer identified, this will be more complicated.

Comment: Default Printer is fine in this case. Thank You for your help with this. :-)

Comment: One other question... Does Access need to be installed on the server that will run the report. I assume the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes, either method requires Access.  The first method calls the MSACCESS.EXE executable directly.  The second automates Access.  You might be able to make it work with the free Access runtime edition, but I haven't tested that.